# WPF ItemTemplateSelector to single item

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemtemplateselector

ItemTemplateSelector is applied to collections of objects - ItemsControl for example.

Is there the same functionality for single items controls? I want to choose a data template taking in consideration a value inside an object. I can do this for lists but not single items.

edit:

In another screen I have this implementation:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path...} ItemTemplateSelector={...}
```

The thing is, now I only have one item and still want to have a itemtemplateselector ...

edit 2:

The question that arises can also be: How can I put just one item in the ItemsSource?

Comment: Wondering if you can just bind Template and use a converter to supply the template...have you tried that?

Comment: gives us some code for your different objects. nevertheless i dont like templateselectors - most time all can achieved with datatemplate and datatype.

Comment: @Charleh: didnt remember that, it maybe a little hack but I think it would work.

blindmeis: I dont like to expose my business objects in the view so I dont use datatypes :(

Comment: @blindmeis some code and more explaination added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that what you are looking for is the [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector) of a ContentControl.